# Can I submit individual form values into a database prior to submitting the entire form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

What I am trying to accomplish, using jQuery, PHP, JS, or really anything that can handle forms and PUT to a database, is to be able to stylize an extremely long form using fieldsets and pass each value into the database to be stored, before submitting the entire form at the end.

What I hope this accomplishes is that if users want to come back and fill out more later, skip questions, etc.. they can do that and have their info stored either way.

Here is what the code block looks like (this is 3 sets of 128):

```
<form id="myForm">
<fieldset>
<label>First Name:</label>
<input data-progression type="text" data-helper="This one is easy!" name="fname" value="" placeholder="$fname"><br>
<div class="note"><p>NOTE: Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p></div>
<div class="bottomFormNav"><span class="left">Next</span></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input data-progression type="text" data-helper="Help users through forms by providing helpful hinters" name="lname" value="" placeholder="$lname"><br>
<div class="note">Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</div>
<div class="bottomFormNav"><span class="right">Back</span><span class="left">Next</span></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label>Address:</label>
<input data-progression type="text" data-helper="Help users through forms by providing helpful hinters" name="address" value="" placeholder="$address"><br>
<div class="bottomFormNav"><span class="right">Back</span><span class="left">Next</span></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Each field is filled out individually and the user clicks "next" which moves that field set out of view and brings in the next one. Could I do something where I could post to the DB when the user hits the next button, and the placeholder'' for each form would then be $fname or $ssn or whichever the variable is in the DB. That way, if its not filled out the value will return blank and appear to need to be filled out.

Thanks for any suggestions & I am open to restructuring or really anything to get this function to work.

Comment: could store it in session variable until form is complete

Comment: The whole issue seems to be very trivial. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would go the approach that @Barry_127 mentioned.  You could build it to pass in a JSON object of values with the parameter names being the column of the table in the database.  That way in your php script you could create a generic parser that would then parse the JSON object and update the values into the database.   Makes the code more scalable and creates reusable functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery's `$.post` function for this.

Something like this:

```
$('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#load').show() //a div overlay with an ajax loading image...
    $.post('link-top-php-script.php', {
        firstName: $('#fname').val(), //give the fname field also the id fname
        lastName: $('#lname').val() //give the lname field also the id lname
        //more fields here
    }, function(data) {
        //after post is successfull
        $('#load').hide(); //hide loading overlay
        //your code for next page here
    }
});
```